# How to get the file name that is currently processing in Jitterbit

Tags: jitterbit

I have a source that maps to a folder that has all .txt files. I have a transformation that picks a file and targets an web api end point. Now how to I get the file name that I just transformed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the global variable: $jitterbit.source.filename

[File Name Global Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4up7h.png)